# Can't test Windows.Services.Store namespace

Tags: uwp, windows-store, msix

I've followed the instructions but can't get this guide to work https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/monetize/in-app-purchases-and-trials#testing.

When I try `StoreContext::GetAssociatedStoreProductsAsync` and `StoreContext::GetStoreProductForCurrentAppAsync` I get the error code 0x803F6107 just like this question [I'm unable to get a proper StoreContext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65023413/im-unable-to-get-a-proper-storecontext).

> If you do not associate your project with an app in the Store, the StoreContext methods set the ExtendedError property of their return values to the error code value 0x803F6107. This value indicates that the Store doesn't have any knowledge about the app.

When I try to debug my project (as per step 5 of the guide) I get this error message:

DEP0700: Registration of the app failed. [0x80073CF3] Windows cannot install package 66MyApp.MyApp_1.0.7.0_x86__2zbdsnss4mwk0 because a different package 66MyApp.MyApp_1.0.7.0_neutral_~*yqhzh56ke71nw with the same name is already installed. Remove package 66MyApp.MyApp_1.0.7.0_neutral*~_yqhzh56ke71nw before installing.

Must the package deployed from visual studio be the same as that downloaded from the store for this to work?

Answer (score 2):

I uploaded a different app and it worked, with the same error message as before. So I'll just have to keep trying things.

I tried to associate my original app with the store identity of the second, and still got 0x803F6107. Then I associated the second app with the store identity of original and succeeded (a third app also successfully associates with both). So it must be a problem with the configuration of the original (maybe it's because I originally created it under a visual studio different account).

Okay so I think I have identified a marker of the problem. The package names of the original always end in __2zbdsnss4mwk0, but all the packages of my new account end in __yqhzh56ke71nw.

Finally, I got I working by creating a new visual studio project and copying my files accross. If the association works then the package ends in __yqhzh56ke71nw (same as that generated from the msixupload file I uploaded to the store), but without associating my packages end in __2zbdsnss4mwk0.